# Need Regular expression

Tags: perl

Can some one tell me the regular expression for below file :

```
Input string 
Exp : 
com.skype.raider
com.instagram.android
com.android.phone
com.android.gallery
com.android.launcher
com.Zeus.webbrowser

Desired Strings(o/p)
com.android.phone
com.android.gallery
com.android.launcher
```

I tried like : $line =~ /com.android.*/ but its not working the way i wanted to be  :(

Comment: Hi! What's you approach? Do you simply need to fetch the 3 desired strings or do they actually follow a pattern?

Comment: `grep '^com\.android' file`

Comment: Ok, if they follow a pattern, then the answer of Richard Priddy might work for you.

Comment: Folks, it's not particularly legitimate to close a question as "unclear what you are asking" AFTER an answer has been accepted, as this establishes the  fact that the asker and the responder understood each other.  Granted, the question probably is not of lasting value and the asker has their solution now, but please don't be so hasty to assume no one else will figure out what you personally cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're looking for a regular expression to match anything that begins with com.android.
If that is the case, try something like this:

```
com\.android\..*
```

Tested using [RegexPlanet](http://fiddle.re/dyjug)

Comment: assuming this each line is input individually then there isn't a need to be more restrictive.